# WSO2 GREG: My SQL setup issues

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Following (https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance450/Setting+up+with+MySQL) instructions I get an error:

```
mysql> -u regadmin -p -Dregdb < 'D:\Programs\wso2greg-5.1.0\dbscripts\mysql.sql';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u regadmin -p -Dregdb < 'D:\Programs\wso2greg-5.1.0\dbscripts\mysql.sql'' at line 1
```

the steps are:

```
create database regdb character set latin1;
GRANT ALL ON regdb.* TO regadmin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "regadmin";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
use regdb
show tables;
quit;
```

Iv'e confirmed drivers copied across - mysql_connector_java_5.1.38_bin_1.0.0.jar.

Iv'e confirmed default datasource updated - master-datasources.xml.

I didn't config any new datasources - I dont think I need them.

I then attempted to create database tables but get error above. Running "wso2server.bat -Dsetup"   just generates following exception, which I assume is because I have no tables.

```
[2015-12-10 18:00:41,251] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil} -  Database Error - Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x91200...' for column 'UM_DESCRIPTION' at row 1 java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x91200...' for column 'UM_DESCRIPTION' at row 1
```

I'm guessing its going to be something trivial - I just don't see it. Ive tried playing around with the mysql syntax but to no avail. I note Governance450 docs say the tables are auto created. I assume the 460 is a valid correction?

-- update
part solved:  not sure exactly what was wrong above (if anything). But following did create tables: (> from dos prompt, mysql> from mysql prompt)

```
> mysql -u root -p

--mysql> drop database if exists regdb;
mysql> create database regdb character set latin1;
--mysql> DROP USER ‘regadmin’@‘localhost’;
mysql> CREATE USER 'regadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'regadmin';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON regdb.* TO 'regadmin'@'localhost';

> mysql -u regadmin -p

mysql> use regdb
mysql> source D:\Programs\wso2greg-5.1.0\dbscripts\mysql.sql;
mysql> show tables;
```

Comment: final issue resolved - Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x91200...' exception seems to derive from the use of character set latin1, omit this and this problem goes away.

Comment: Can you post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The steps I followed that eventually worked for me were:-

```
> mysql -u root -p

--mysql> drop database if exists regdb;
mysql> create database regdb;

--mysql> DROP USER ‘regadmin’@‘localhost’;
mysql> CREATE USER 'regadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'regadmin';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON regdb.* TO 'regadmin'@'localhost';

> mysql -u regadmin -p

mysql> use regdb
mysql> source D:\Programs\wso2greg-5.1.0\dbscripts\mysql.sql;
mysql> show tables;
```

where

```
Dos prompt     >
mysqlprompt    mysql>
```